Optimal rotation matrix
Context: I am trying to adapt the Rigid point set registration algorithm from Point Set Registration: Coherent Point Drift to include rotation information.
My problem can be stated as follows:
$\max_{R\in \mathbb{R}^{2x2}}tr(A^TR)$ s.t. $R^TR=I$, $\det(R)=1$, and $|angle(R)-\theta|<\delta$
with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2x2}$, $\theta$ and $\delta$ given.
If it weren't for the constraint on the angle, the closed form solution for $R$ is given Lemma 1 in On the Closed-Form Solution of the Rotation Matrix Arising in Computer Vision Problems:

Suppose the closed form solution from the lemma, call it $R'$, has an angle $\alpha$, then there are two cases. If $|\alpha - \theta|<\delta$, $R'$ is the solution to the original problem. If $R'$ does not satisfy the angle constraint, take $R$ with angle $\beta=\theta + \delta$ or $\theta - \delta$, whichever is closest to $\alpha$. Is my reasoning in the second case correct?
